# Message[Playground.this.KafkaHealthEvent] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

Tags: scala

I've got a warning on the following code:

```
sealed trait KafkaHealthEvent
case object KafkaInactiveApproved extends KafkaHealthEvent
case object KafkaActiveApproved extends KafkaHealthEvent


sealed trait SapHealthEvent
case object SapInactiveApproved extends SapHealthEvent
case object SapActiveApproved extends SapHealthEvent


sealed trait ServerHealthStreamer

case object Complete extends ServerHealthStreamer
case class Message[A](msg: A) extends ServerHealthStreamer

val msg: ServerHealthStreamer = Message[KafkaHealthEvent](KafkaActiveApproved)

msg match {
  case Complete => 
    println("Complete")
  case m: Message[KafkaHealthEvent] =>
    println(m.msg)  
}
```

and the warning is:

```
non-variable type argument Playground.this.KafkaHealthEvent in type pattern Playground.this.Message[Playground.this.KafkaHealthEvent] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

How to solve the problem? The type variable of the `Message` case class can be either `KafkaHealthEvent` or `SapHealthEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjusting your pattern match should work:

```
msg match {
  case Complete => 
    println("Complete")
  case Message(msg:KafkaHealthEvent) =>
    println(msg)  
  case other => // handle unexpected
}
```

Here is a blog that explains Type Erasure: http://squidarth.com/scala/types/2019/01/11/type-erasure-scala.html

Comment: Then I've got `match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Message((x: Any forSome x not in Playground.this.KafkaHealthEvent))`

Comment: yes you need to handle any possible type - so if you are not interested in the other cases you can add a catch all - see my edited answer